# How to install Python Pynamical package (module)

Tags: python

I am using PyCharm Community Edition 2017 with interpreter python 3.6.1. I want to install pynamical module.But it is showing error. I am posting here the error message:

```
E:\untitled>pip install pynamical

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
error: command 
'c:\\users\\s.chakraborty\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\ 
python.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try `python -m pip install pynamical`

Comment: TRy using pip to install in your terminal instead of pycharm.

Comment: After using "python -m pip install pynamical" command, the same error is coming.

Answer (score 2):

In pycharm has a module to install new package easly.

Go to

> File->Settings->Project:Name->Project Interpreter  and click '+'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install [pynamical](https://github.com/gboeing/pynamical) is to open a command prompt (on windows) or a terminal (on mac/linux) then run `conda install -c conda-forge pynamical` per the [documentation](https://pynamical.readthedocs.io).